# How can i use ember js without ember-cli with PHP or java?

Tags: java, php, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

How can I use ember js without ember-cli with PHP or java? How can I interact with back end data? Any example will be much appreciated.

Comment: Ajax and json. As it stands, this question is too broad to be answered

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you'll need to understand, is that *ember-cli* is a command line interface. It acts as a blueprint generator and an asset pipeline and glues all the ember stuff together in a wonderful productive package. It's just standard now, and you wouldn't want to use *Ember* without *CLI*. They are basically now the same thing unless you were using Ember since pre 1.13 and can't upgrade.

Ember is a JavaScript framework for front-end/client-side user interface. It doesn't deal with server style data storage like a traditional Apache/PHP. In a PHP setup, each page is rendered on the server side and then delivered to the browser in a complete form. Ember is more like a shell that you fill with data from somewhere else, but also has the ability to manipulate that data in the browsers and persist it back to the data-source.

The data source could really be something as simple as local storage. Maybe a simple game that just stores your userScore in the built-in local storage.

The data source could be something like the WordPress API, where ember pulls in posts or page data to display on the screen. Maybe you even have a form that persists new posts back to the server.

You could use parse or firebase for real-time back-end as a service. Or you could build a server of any sort that was able to generate an API that Ember could consume.

Currently, rails is popular for the server. Also, node frameworks like hapi.js and sails. Elixr and Pheonix are gaining interest and have proven to be a powerful backend team with Ember.

Ember uses ember-data and adapters to take in API data and serialize into a simple set of conventions.

If you have API endpoints coming from PHP or Java, you could use them - however, if you are starting a new project - I wouldn't think that would be an ideal route.

You can follow the Ember guides tutorial to learn more about how Ember works. Good luck!.

Comment: A comprehensive answer to a broad question. I guess it isn't very clear to Ember newcomers that it is so easily "pluggable" (in fact that's _exactly_ what it is) to any back-end. So the user is free to pick its data source from a multitude of choices, from programming languages to online services to in-memory stores, and so on.